# Receive messages within a time frame from google pub/sub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to only receive messages within a time frame, as the messages before and after have corrupted data.

I know that I can **seek** to the starting position, so that issue is solved, how do I configure the other end (stop at a specific time).

Any answers or suggestions are highly appreciated. 
After setting the interval I plan to read the messages from python code if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no integrated solution for that. You have to implement a filter in Python for discarding messages with corrupted data.

However, your use case is interesting and opening a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) could help you (and others) in the future.